# Apache2 Reverse Proxy HTTPS Error During SSL Handshake

Tags: ssl, proxy, apache2, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I am setting up Apache2 as a "gateway" inside a private network.
I am trying to forward HTTPS Traffic from outside through internal network with apache2.

I got it to work with HTTP but as soon as I switched to HTTPS it doesnt work anymore.

The error that I get is:

```
[Tue May 02 14:52:51.347146 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 5423:tid 140612283090496] [client my.ip:17059] AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /
[Tue May 02 14:52:51.347161 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 5423:tid 140612283090496] [client my.ip:17059] AH01097: pass request body failed to 100.100.100.100:553 (100.100.100.100) from 100.100.100.100 ()
[Tue May 02 14:52:51.397245 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 5423:tid 140612145747520] [client my.ip:17060] AH00898: DNS lookup failure for: 100.100.100.100:553favicon.ico returned by /favicon.ico, referer: https://example.com:2230/
```

My Config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:2230>
        ServerName example.com
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy/access.log combined

         <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Authtype Basic
        Authname "Password Required"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
        Require valid-user
        </Proxy>

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProxyEngine on
        SSLProxyVerify none
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
        SSLProxyProtocol +TLSv1
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf


        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / https://100.100.100.100:553
        ProxyPassReverse / https://100.100.100.100:553
</VirtualHost>
```

Does someone have an ideea which can be the issue?

Comment: *"I got it to work with HTTP "* - please show how this working setup looked like. My guess is that you while enabling HTTPS on the reverse proxy also switched the ProxyPass protocol from `http://` to `https://` - without actually making any changes to the specified backend server. This will not work, i.e. if you actually want the backend to be access using HTTPS by the reverse proxy than you need to actually configure it appropriately.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich the config looked the same but without the SSL Parameters. The Specified Server which it gets proxypass to has SSL Activated.
I also tried for example to proxypass to an webserver of mine which also has SSL Activated.

Comment: The config you show does not match the error messages. The error is about problems with proxying to 100.100.100.100 port 17059 while in your config you are proxying to port 553.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I dont have another config. Only the default config is activated but i didnt edit anything there, its just the apache2 default config.

Comment: I just noticed what you mean. There is a confusion because I edited the IPs.
The 100.100.100.100 port 17059 that you mean is my WAN IP and I am trying to reach this : 100.100.100.100:553favicon.ico